# 301 Redirect from www.example.com/this to that.example.com

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect www.example.com/this/ or example.com/this/ to that.example.com

At the moment in my .htaccess file I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com/this$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://that.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However this is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache mod_alias [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) is much more simple, you could try something like this:

```
Redirect /this http://that.example.com/
```

Answer (score 2):

`%HTTP_HOST` will only match the hostname (www.example.com). You'll also need to match on `%REQUEST_URI`, then use that to insert into the rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/(.*)$
```